# How to add reference under COM link in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, pocketpc

I want to create a Pocket PC application for a handheld device. In order to create and deploy application i am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version (for Smart device project with C#).

But I need to add reference under COM link in the project. How can i do that? (It is OK for VS 2022 but not for VS2008) Also, how can i change my target platform as x86 in VS 2008 for smart device project (Pocket PC app)?? (Even if I create a new target platform from configuration manager it doesn't change).

**Note:** For example, i can add reference under COM link in the Visual Studio 2022 or newest but cannot same thing in VS 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Adding reference under COM link is OK for newest versions of VS but not VS08.

Also, target platform selection is OK for Windows Form applications but not for Smart Device Projects.

Comment: Why don't you update VS? 2008 is _a n c i e n t_.

Comment: I have to use VS08 to create a smart device app. After VS2008, Microsoft stopped providing support for smart device applications. So, unfortunately I cannot use newest versions of VS for my projects.

Comment: And there wasn't a suitable replacement? ... Hmmm. Does it _have_ to be a "Smart Device App"? Upvoting to get attention of someone with knowledge. There _has_ to be a way ...

Comment: Actually i am not sure about that but i am sure it have to be PocketPC application. Firstly, I tried the project with VS2022 Winforms application but it did not work on handheld device. Thank you Fildor;)

Comment: Yes, you are totally right Adrian.. I am new user in the platform so I try to change the title. Thank you for your caution.

Comment: Hello, Visual Studio 2008 is so old that it is difficult to find relevant information and reproduce it. I found [Creating a Managed COM Add-in with Visual Studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/infopath/external-automation/how-to-create-a-com-add-in-to-add-custom-features-to-infopath#creating-a-managed-com-add-in-with-visual-studio-2005-or-visual-studio-2008). Hope to help you.